# How to automatically close the dialog box?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dialog

I have a WinForm application that have an automatic logout after some time without activity performed by the user, that application have some dialog box like

```
SearchCustomer.ShowDialog()
```

If the user left that dialog opened and the time expire the user is automatically logged out but that dialog box remains opened, so anybody can use that dialog even with the user logged out.

There's any way to close those dialog box from main Form?

**Edit:**
There's another Dialog box opened in a different way

```
AddCustomer.Show()
AddCustomer.BringToFront()
```

**Edit 2** Solution based on jmcilhinney answer

```
For Each openForm In openForms

    Dim H1 As Integer = openForm.GetHashCode()
    Dim H2 As Integer = Me.GetHashCode()
    If H1 <> H2 Then 'No igual
       openForm.Close()
    End If
Next
```

Comment: It is just this dialog or there are other situations like this in other dialogs?

Comment: `SearchCustomer.Close` will close that form

Comment: @Steve Yes there's another that are opened in a different way, I add the code to the main question, please re read, thanks.

Comment: @MattWilko Can I perform that instruction from any part in the main Form? As far I now, probably I'm wrong, the code execution of the main Form stop at ShowDialog() until the Dialog is closed; I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested but I would think that you should be able to do something along these lines:

```
Dim openForms = My.Application.OpenForms.Cast(Of Form)().ToArray()

For Each openForm In openForms
    openForm.Close()
Next
```

Comment: It closes the dialog box, but also the main Form.

Comment: So, inside the loop, test whether `openForm` is the main form and then only close it if it's not.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to figure out how. I'm looking for some property that help to identify the main Form, Can I make something like If Not openForm = Me?

Comment: I think I got it! I just use the hashcode property.

Comment: I would think that you could just use the type, unless you have multiple instances of that type of form open at some time. E.g. `If Not TypeOf openForm Is Form1 Then`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option.

Open your form with the ownership attribute.

```
    AddCustomer.Show(Me)
    'This open the form and gives the referring form ownership.
    'It Also gives focus to the child form, keeping it on top of the referring form
```

When the referring form closes, so does the child form.

Comment: Interesting but is not what I need. I need that the main Form remains open and just close all the child forms when the user is logged out. Anyway, I have this solved. Thanks anyway.